# "Failed to open \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\grub64.efi", etc

Tags: boot, 13.10, uefi

A while ago, my primary HDD failed, taking my EFI partition with it. However, my Ubuntu system files are kept on my secondary SSD. When I got a new HDD, I created an EFI partition using GParted on a live CD, and then ran Boot Repair. Now, whenever I boot, I get this error, which displays for about a half second before the Ubuntu splash screen appears:

[image: EFI Error]

```
Failed to open \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\grub64.efi - 8000000000000000E
Failed to load image
Failed to open \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\grub64.efi - 8000000000000000E
Failed to load image
Could not open "\EFI\BOOT\fallback.efi": 14
Failed to open \EFI\BOOT\grub64.efi - 8000000000000000E
Failed to load image
Failed to open \EFI\BOOT\MokManager.efi - 8000000000000000E
Failed to load image
```

The system continues to boot normally after it appears. I checked, and the listed files are indeed missing from `/boot/efi`. I've already tried running Boot Repair again, as well as `update-grub`. What can I do to resolve this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the computer is booting, the safest approach is to ignore the messages, since they're nothing but an eyesore -- and one that lasts for less than a second, according to your report. Any attempt to fix the problem runs the risk of creating bigger problems.

If you want to proceed, I recommend you examine two things:

- The output of the command `sudo efibootmgr -v`. This may show stray entries in the firmware for the missing files. If so, removing those entries (with `efibootmgr` -- type `man efibootmgr` to learn about its use) may remove the error messages.
- The contents of the `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file. This is the GRUB configuration file, and it may have references to those files. Unfortunately, editing `grub.cfg` is tricky; you don't normally edit it directly, but instead rely on scripts to construct it. Thus, unless you're an expert, I reiterate my initial advice to ignore the problem; or if you're really offended by those messages, it may be easier to switch to my [rEFInd boot manager](http://www.rodsbooks.com/refind/) than to try to fix GRUB.

Comment: Wound up letting it be and doing a fresh install for 14.04, which has cleared everything up.