# Two problems: I can't boot my Ubuntu Line DVD and getting GRUB error

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning, dvd

Problem:

I can't boot my Live Ubuntu DVD on my laptop.

I'm trying to install another bootable Ubuntu (16.04.2) partition on my laptop, however I can't boot from my Live DVD. My BIO is set to boot from DVD first. The Live DVD works well on other computers so it's not my DVD.

The GRUB boot menu does allow me to boot the other two OS on the hard drive.

I also get the following error at boot:

```
Failed to open \EFI\BOOT\grubx64.efi 80000000000
Failed to load grup
Failed to open \EFI\Microsoft\Boot\grubx64.efi 80000000000
Failed to load grup
Failed to open \EFI\BOOT\grubx64.efi 80000000000
Secure boot not enabled
```

I'm not sure how to mount \EFI to verify or repair the problem files.

I tried doing a grub repair, below is the output of the repair:
http://paste.ubuntu.com/25126731/

So I think GRUB is preventing me from booting the LIVE DVD.

Note:  I just upgraded this disk from a 500gig to a 1 terabyte disk via some sector to sector copy program.  So this may have caused the problem.

Comment: All of those are infos and not error messages. See https://askubuntu.com/questions/412905/failed-to-open-efi-microsoft-boot-grub64-efi-etc. The Boot-Info log of the currently installed operating systems is inconsequential to the one on the Live DVD. I recommend that you look at https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it.

Comment: You might have created UEFI trouble caused by the copy action.  Before any further trials I would recommand to make a copy of each partition, so you could at the last resort wipe the disk, make a clean install with the DVD (I recommend legacy for under 2TB disks) and then just replace the clean installation partition with your copy. Could even be faster than interative fix trials. Works also with windows partitions.

Answer (score 1):

It's unclear from your description whether you're booting from the DVD drive or from GRUB on your hard disk. The latter is unlikely to do you any good.

Most computers provide a built-in boot manager that enables you to select a specific boot program or device on a one-time basis. How you access this tool varies from one computer to another, but it's typically via a function key (usually F8 or above), Del, or Enter, pressed early in the boot process. Try using that. If you see two entries for the DVD drive, pick the one that includes "UEFI" in its name.

Note also that just because a disc boots in one computer does not mean it will work in another. There are computer-to-computer differences in optical drives, so a disc that's readable on one computer may not be readable in another. Also, Ubuntu's installation disc images are intended to be booted in both BIOS mode and in EFI mode. You may have booted in one mode, but the target computer might be trying to boot in the other mode; or the target computer might have a problem with the disc image (it uses a Frankenstein's Monster sort of format that *usually* works, but that some computers find objectionable).

For all these reasons, you might want to try transferring the disc image to a USB flash drive and booting in that way. I recommend either using `dd` to copy the image to the USB drive as a whole or using [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/) in Windows to do the job. If you use Rufus, be sure to select an option to make an EFI-compatible disk.

---

***EDIT:***

Try this:

1. Create a USB stick using Rufus.
2. Using whatever computer and OS you can, access the Rufus-created USB stick. It should have a directory called `EFI/BOOT`. (That name may vary in case.)
3. Rename `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` to something else (or delete it entirely).
4. Rename `EFI/BOOT/grubx64.efi` to `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi`.
5. Try again.

This procedure is based on the observation that the "Failed to open..." messages look like they're produced by Shim, which is Ubuntu's way of dealing with Secure Boot. On a bootable installation medium, Shim is stored as `EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi` and launches `EFI/BOOT/grubx64.efi`; however, this doesn't seem to be working for you. Since your errors also note that Secure Boot is not enabled, though, Shim isn't really necessary, so you *should* be able to boot by renaming GRUB to use the fallback filename (`EFI/BOOT/bootx64.efi`), which is what's used to boot external media.

Comment: I'm booting from my DVD drive.

Comment: I'm booting from my DVD drive.  I have also tried booting from a USB stick and I have the exact same issue where it does not let me boot Ubuntu Live from a USB stick.  The BIOS (UEFI) allows me to specify which device to boot from.  However the option for CD/DVD does not seem to have an EFI mode option.  What should I try next?  Thank you.

Comment: I just created another Live Ubuntu USB stick, this time using Rufus.  This stick has the same problem on this laptop.  However this new stick works well on my other computers.  Could it be something with my bios?  At one time I was able to boot this laptop with Live USB sticks, now I can not!

Comment: See my edit, above.